# Changing shell in a Veewee script

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, vagrant, veewee

I'm in the process of building out my first Vagrant box using Veewee (ubuntu 12.04) and, about 95% of the way there, I'm stuck on something. I have a custom post-install script, called right after `postinstall.sh`, that builds out my preferred user environment. It...

- Installs curl, zsh & git
- Installs oh-my-zsh
- Writes a custom theme file
- Writes a custom .zshrc file

All of that seems to be fine, but the next logical step is to change my shell so that it's all ready to go when I `vagrant ssh` for the first time, but I'm stuck. The last line of this script is `chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh`, but it doesn't take. Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way of changing the shell from the script? I suppose I could update `/etc/passwd` with sed, but...ugh. Be nice if it could be done in a cleaner way than that.

Also, while trying to run down this issue, I discovered another possible issue. I don't have passwordless sudo access. In the packaged `postinstall.sh` script, I see that it's running set to make that happen, but in 12.04, at least, `/etc/sudoers` is read-only which probably prevents the change from getting made.

Anyone else noticed these things? Any hints on how to work around them? My searches have turned up nothing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me whilst installing Ubuntu 12.04.3 with Vagrant (aka "precise32"): since the default vagrant password is just "vagrant":

```
echo "vagrant" | chsh -s /bin/zsh
```